# Ansible - Reading Environment Variable from Remote Host

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I am trying to read an Environment variable from Target Linux Host using Ansible playbook. I tried all the below tasks as per the document but there is no result.

```
   - name: Test1    
     debug: msg="{{ ansible_env.BULK }}"
     delegate_to: "{{ target_host }}"

   - name: Test2  
     shell: echo $BULK
     delegate_to: "{{ target_host }}"
     register: foo

   - debug: msg="{{ foo.stdout }}"

   - name: Test3 
     debug: msg="{{ lookup('env','BULK')}} is an environment variable"
     delegate_to: "{{ target_host }}"
```

The Environment variable "BULK" is not set in the local Host where I am executing the playbook, so I assume its returning nothing. Instead of BULK, if I use "HOME" which is always available, it returns the result.  If I SSH into the target_host I am able to run `echo $BULK` without any issue.

How to obtain the Environment variable from the remote host?

Comment: Why do you use `delegate_to` in every task?

Comment: @techraf:  There are multiple tasks in this yaml file. Few tasks run in localhost and few in the targethost .This is just for testing,all three tasks perform the same operation . If I am able to read the Environment variable I will delete the other two .

Answer (score 2):

> If I SSH into the target_host I am able to run `echo $BULK` without any issue.

Most likely, because `BULK` is set in one of the rc-files sourced only in an interactive session of the shell on the target machine. And Ansible's `gather_facts` task runs in a non-interactive one.

> How to obtain the Environment variable from the remote host?

Move the line setting the `BULK` variable to a place where it is sourced regardless of the session type (where exactly, depends on the target OS and shell)

See for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/133107 for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Remote environment variables will be automatically gathered by ansible during the "Gathering Facts" task.

You can inspect them like this:

```
- name: inspect env vars
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.env
```

In your case try this:

```
- name: Test4 
  debug: msg="{{ ansible_facts.env.BULK }} is the value of an environment variable"
```

Answer (score 0):

### source `/etc/profile` and then grep the `env`

my solution is not perfect, but often works. for example i want to check if the remote_host has environment variables for proxy servers, i do the following:

#### as an adhoc ansible command:

```
ansible remote_host -b -m shell -a '. /etc/profile && (env | grep -iP "proxy")'
```

#### Explanation:

- i prefere the shell module, it does what i expect... the same if i do it on a shell
- `. /etc/profile` sources the /etc/profile. And this file sources other files like under /etc/profile.d . So after this i have the fix machine part of the environment.
- `env | grep -iP "proxy"` then filter the expanded environment for my variables i am looking for